# vs code - How is this python (3.7) packages structure working in AWS Lambda but not in local (vs code) environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

This is a fairly straight-forward structure containing two packages each with their own modules.

My understanding is this this has something to do with python not being to find the path of packages/project-folder despite having `__init__.py`

My questions are:

- What's the correct/clean way to get this structure working on vs code? (preferably, an OS, package-manager agnostic approach)
- How is this working in AWS Lambda?

[image]

```
# main.py
from app.my_package import main_module

def handler(event, context):
    main_module.do_something()

---

# main_module.py
from app.shared_package import shared_module

def do_something():
    print('\nThis is printed from app_module')
    print('Calling a function in shared_module')
    shared_module.print_something()

---

# shared_module.py
def print_something():
    print('This is printed from shared_module\n')
```

When run from Windows or Linux machine: (tried virtualenv as well)

[image]
[image]

When invoked using AWS Lambda:

[image]

References:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: What is your `PYTHONPATH` env var? Maybe AWS has it set to `.` so it allows you to import any module in the current working directoy.

Comment: You probably need to launch your app with `python -m app.mypackage.main` rather than `python app/my_package/main.py`. That is, reference using a *module path* rather than a *filesystem path*. If that doesn't work then it's because your module path is wrong, probably because you need to run the command from the directory that contains the `app` folder.

Comment: thanks @DanielPryden. invoking it from project folder works. `python -m app.my_package.main`.